# Recibir datos que envio por AJAX a Controlador

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter-3

Hola buenas tardes tengo un problema al obtener datos que envio por AJAX a un Controlador

Datos que envio por AJAX

```
var txtDateInicio = document.getElementById('date_inicio').value;
var txtDateFin = document.getElementById('date_fin').value;
var parametros = {
    "txtDateInicio" : txtDateInicio,
    "txtDateFin" : txtDateFin
};

$.ajax({
    url : url,
    type: "POST",
    data: parametros,
    success: function(data) {
        window.location.href = "<?php echo base_url('index.php/login_controller/perfil_calls')?>";
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('Error al filtrar');
    }
});
```

Los quiero obtener el mi Controlador

```
public function perfil_calls() {

}
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar.

Gracias

Comment: Supongo que el detalle esta en que no estas definiendo la url del ajax. Si aun tienes problemas con esto, comenta. Ha seria bueno que mostrases como tienes tu formulario, tus rutas y como has intentado definir tu controlador; con esto se puede analizar mejor en donde puede estar el detalle.

Answer (score 0):

Al mandar a llamar la función con `POST` se reciben de manera normal como si fuera un formulario con el `tag` de `method='post'`, entonces tu código en el controlador sería el siguiente:

```
public function perfil_calls() {
    $dateInicio = $this->input->post('txtDateInicio');
    $dateFin = $this->input->post('txtDateFin');
}
```

Para mayor información una respuesta de SO:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39461369/how-does-codeigniter-receive-the-ajax-post-data-in-controller

Comment: No me marca error pero hago un echo en el contradora y no me muetra nada y si estoy enviando datos porque en el javascript hago un alert de los datos y si existe.

Comment: Los datos que envio son fechas

Comment: Si esta llegando al controlador correcto? Si haces algún echo "Hello World" si se pinta?